# Is there a way to know when all connections/transactions on a database are closed in IndexedDB?

Tags: html, indexeddb

I'm running in to an issue where I call close on a database connection prior to upgrading, but even though `IDBDatabase.close()` returns, it's not actually done closing everything so it throws a `blocked` event (although it allows my upgrade to continue). Is there a way I can tie the upgrade call to when the transactions are actually all done being closed?

Answer (score 2):

> call close on a database connection prior to upgrading

You don't call `close` in this case.

Call `close` if you no longer use the connection or the connection is no longer usable.

Comment: I would like to add, manage your db connections. Don't start opening connections and just let them exist. Either close them if the work is done, or keep track of them. It will save you issues like db blocks and performance issues